# Dividend paying stock's risk-neutral probability proof

Tags: probability, finance

Question: Consider the one-period binomial model with a stock that pays continuous dividend $\delta$. I want to show that the risk-neutral probability is given by $$p=\frac{\exp((r-\delta)\Delta t)-d}{u-d}$$.
Hint: The value of stock at time $\Delta t$ is: $S_0uexp(-\delta\Delta t)$ for stock moving up and $S_0dexp(\delta\Delta t)$ for stock moving down.

Approach: Here is how I started the proof.
First I form portfolio at t=0. $\Delta S-O_{t=0}$ to find $\Delta$ which is;
$$\Delta S_0uexp(\delta\Delta t)-O_{up}=\Delta S_0dexp(\delta\Delta t)-O_{down}$$ where $$\Delta=\frac{O_{up}-O_{down}}{S_0exp(\delta\Delta t)(u-d)}$$
after finding this $\Delta$ I'm sure we are supposed to substitute it into the initial portfolio but I'm confused as to how am I supposed to get rid of the O's and how to derive p from this. The professor gave me this much hint.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: Please explain notation (such as $u$,$d$).Risk-neutral probability $p$ is the probability which justfies a stock's price for a risk-neutral investor. For a risk-neutral investor, price $S_0=e^{-r\Delta t}(pS_0ue^{\delta t}+(1-p)S_0de^{\delta t})$. Solve for $p$.

Comment: so u r saying that $S_0$ is this value? well if I solve it for p for sure I will get what I want.. But how come my Professor didn't teach this in class and in the hint he gave us $$O_{t=0}=exp(-r\Delta t)*(pO_{up,t=T}+(1-p)O_{down,t=T})$$ where O is the call option.

Comment: The equation you mention for Call option pricing is correct and it uses risk-neutral probabilities. If you knew the option price using some other  method, you could use even this equation to determine risk-neutral probabilities. But typically, this equation is used to price the option after determining risk-neutral probabilities from the equation for stock price I mentioned. This latter equation is simply saying that  the price of a stock is the present value of future cash flows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, its more beneficial to work via first principles, than plugging into an equation.

Let $X$ denote a claim -- in this case $X$ denotes the payoff on the stock held at time $t$. Lets simplify the notation, so that without loss of generality let $t=0$ and $t=1$, and suppose the stock has a value $u$ or $d$ at $t=1$.

What we want is the value of the claim $X$ at time $t=0$, under the *risk neutral measure*. Denote this measure by $p$. Thus we want to find $p$, given that we know the possible prices of the stock. That is if $X_{1}(u),X_{1}(d)$ represent the claim at time t=1, we have that.

\begin{equation}
V(X) = pX_{1}(u) + (1-p)X_{1}(d) 
\end{equation}

Now $V(X) = S_{0}exp(r\Delta t)$, since the stock price at $t=0$ is known. Thus we have,
\begin{equation}
S_{0}exp(r\Delta t) = pX_{1}(u) + (1-p)X_{1}(d) 
\end{equation}
$X_{1}(u)$ is the claim at t=1, when the market is in state $u$. That is use the hint given to calculate $X_{1}(u)$ and $X_{1}(d)$, plug it into the equation above and solve for $p$. Hope this helps, let me know if you need more details.